# Proteger endereço de memória

Tags: javascript, java, c#

Estou desenvolvendo um game simples. Quero proteger o endereço de memória onde fica localizada a pontuação do jogador para que somente um processo em específico possa acessa-la, evitando assim que o usuário altere ou acesse este endereço de memória com uma ferramenta de cheat. Isso é possível?

Answer (score 0):

Use a documentação do Windows

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx

```
BOOL WINAPI CreateProcess(
  _In_opt_    LPCTSTR               lpApplicationName,
  _Inout_opt_ LPTSTR                lpCommandLine,
  _In_opt_    LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpProcessAttributes,
  _In_opt_    LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpThreadAttributes,
  _In_        BOOL                  bInheritHandles,
  _In_        DWORD                 dwCreationFlags,
  _In_opt_    LPVOID                lpEnvironment,
  _In_opt_    LPCTSTR               lpCurrentDirectory,
  _In_        LPSTARTUPINFO         lpStartupInfo,
  _Out_       LPPROCESS_INFORMATION lpProcessInformation
);
```

ou

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682453(v=vs.85).aspx

```
HANDLE WINAPI CreateThread(
  _In_opt_  LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES  lpThreadAttributes,
  _In_      SIZE_T                 dwStackSize,
  _In_      LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE lpStartAddress,
  _In_opt_  LPVOID                 lpParameter,
  _In_      DWORD                  dwCreationFlags,
  _Out_opt_ LPDWORD                lpThreadId
);
```

Perceba o parâmetro das duas funções cujo tipo é LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES. Segundo a documentação da Microsoft, se o valor for NULL o processo ou thread são criados sem herança a processos filhos. Mas se quiser fazer algo mais seguro, estude sobre a struct SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES.